# Generalized Arithmetico-Geometic series with a possible application

Tags: arithmetic-progressions, geometric-progressions

While playing with Arithmetico-Geometric progression formula(i.e
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}(a+(k-1)d)y^{k-1} = \frac{a-[a+(n-1)d]y^n}{1-y} +\frac{1-y^{n-1}}{(1-y)^2}yd$$
I realized it could be generalized as:
If $x \ne y$,
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}(a+kd)x^{n-k}y^k = \frac{ax^{n+1}-(a+nd)y^{n+1}}{x-y} +\frac{x^n-y^n}{(x-y)^2}xyd$$
Though, I can't prove this yet.

> **QUESTION:**
> If per chance the claim is correct, Is it safe to say, if $-1\le x \le 1$, $-1\le y \le 1$, that
> $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(a+kd)x^{n-k}y^k = 0$$

Comment: It is obviously not true if $x=y=1.$

Comment: All your formulae are finite sums, until  your last sum.

Comment: $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}(a+kd)x^{n-k}y^k= x^n\sum_{k=0}^{n}(a+kd)\left(\frac{y}x\right)^k$$ so you can use your original equation when $x\neq 0.$ Then show $x=0$ separately, using $0^0=1, 0^k=0$ for $k>0.$

Comment: What if $x≠y$ and $x$ and $y$ range from -1 to 1?